# How to remove the "path" above a figure

Tags: graphics, floats

How to remove the text "LaTeX tutorial/STA9700 Project/fig1.jpg" above the figure:
[image]

my code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

......

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3in]{E:/Dropbox/learning Latex/LaTeX tutorial/STA9700 Project/fig1.jpg}
    \caption[Optional caption]{CHN vs. US in 2008 Olympics}
    \label{fig: Cover Picture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: See [How to take out the File Path above my image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/700376)